# Pass prop from intermediate component into props.children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'd like to make a functional component which gives a prop to its immediate children. I don't want to use a context because I want it to only be available to the immediate children.

So given the following components:

```
const TopLevel = () => {
  return (
    <FooGiver>
      <LowerLevel />
    </FooGiver>
  )
}

interface LowerLevelProps {
  foo?: string;
}
const LowerLevel = ({foo}: LowerLevelProps) => {
  return foo ? <p>{foo}</p> : <p>No foo provided</p> 
}

const FooGiver = ({ children }: FooGiverProps) => {
  const foo = bar // TODO: This should set its children's `foo` prop to "bar"
 
  return (
    <>
      { children }
    </>
  )
}
```

Is it possible to define `FooGiver` such that it will give any children it receives a `foo` prop of `"bar"`?

If so, would I need to continue to keep the `foo` prop optional, or would TS pick up that `FooGiver` will always set `foo`, and not complain that I called `<LowerLevel />` without providing the required `foo` prop?

Comment: have you tried `.prop` on the child?

Answer (score 0):

I think this would do it to add props to all children

The following example component adds a new props named `newProp` with value `true` to all children it takes.

```
function Parent({children}){
    return <>

        {children.map(child=>{
            const modified = child;
            modified.props["newProp"] = true;//add new value to prop
            return modified
        })}

    </>
}
```